# Verificar la autenticidad de la aplicación de un cliente

Tags: c#, seguridad, servidor

Tengo un problema en lo que a seguridad respecta en modelos cliente-servidor.

Imaginemos el siguiente escenario (cliente-servidor).

Una aplicación cliente (WinForms) quiere comunicarse con un servidor (Peticiones Http (GET o POST) en PHP, Sockets o WebSockets en C#).

El primer problema que surge es que tanto si el servidor (esté escrito en PHP o en C#) debe tener algún tipo de control para las peticiones anónimas que el cliente genere, para ello, tendremos que usar algún tipo de token generado por el servidor para cada petición.

El problema no está en la seguridad que se le otorgue a dicha token (tengo pensado en usar HTTPS (PHP) o SSL/TLS + Certificados en WebSockets (C#) para las comunicaciones cliente-servidor a nivel de red, para evitar Spoofing o MiTM.

El problema está a la hora de otorgar la token. Ya que sería muy fácil otorgar a cualquier cliente una token por parte del servidor. (Pequeña aclaración: ya que sería fácil coger y replicar un cliente que haga peticiones al servidor para intentar obtener tokens validas, al menos, como yo tengo pensado implementarlo, de ahí a que necesite ayuda)

En lo que estaba pensando, es generar un resumen md5 o sha para la assembly del cliente, y así si cualquier persona intenta replicar dichos pasos, lo tendrá dificil, ya que modificar el source code de la assembly o hacer una assembly maliciosa y obtener el mismo hash por colisión es dificil.

Lo que no sé es como de eficiente sería este sistema, por ello necesito que me guíen un poco en este aspecto.

He estado mirando OAuth, y creo que este tipo de implementación no es la que busco, ya que este tipo de implementaciones es a nivel de usuario (para que otro usuario no vulnere los datos de x usuario), no de cliente (aplicación) como tal.

Así que si alguien puede arrojar algo de luz en este asunto sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Veo que miraste el tour. Por como esta planteada la pregunta, parece muy basada en opiniones. Podrias tratar de evitar que fuera asi?

Comment: Aún no he implementado nada, solamente estoy documentandome acerca del tema, y claro, he planteado el problema para el caso extremo de que un hacker intente replicar las peticiones del cliente al servidor para obtener tokens validas y comprometer la seguridad.

Comment: El tema es que en este sitio esta clase de preguntas se considera basada en opiniones. Tal vez puedas pasarte por el [chat] y recibir alguna ayuda? es muy probable que como esta planteada termine cerrada

Comment: En la comunidad en inglés he visto una pregunta similar de 2009 que casi es como yo planteo el problema, pero claro, necesito más información, y no es cuestión de revivir una pregunta de hace 9 años. Llevo toda la tarde chateando por telegram sin suerte, probaré en el chat de esta comunidad (gracias), pero a lo que a mi respecta, estoy pidiendo posibles soluciones a las vulnerabilidades de un token.

Comment: Esta comunidad no funciona como la de ingles.. y las reglas del 2009 a ahora han cambiado un poco ;) por eso te decia.

Comment: Ah vale, perdona, eso no lo sabía, vale bueno, voy a hacer lo del chat y esperare a que cierren el tema. Gracias.

Comment: Mira los JWT, hay librerías en los principales lenguajes y son estándar.
La búsqueda de “jwt español” en google te da excelentes webs y blogs para aprender su uso, mejor de lo que te podría explicar aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Usar el un hash del binario es fácil de atacar, con un sniffer y un certificado auto firmado instado en el pc se pueden ver las peticiones que hace el cliente y obtener el toquen que siempre es el mismo, no se modifica sofware se crea uno nuevo que lo impersonalice. Puedes hacer las coas mas complicadas definendo que el servidor le mande un string aleatorio ("challenge") para que el cliente lo firme con una llave privada RSA y envié de vuelta la información al servidor, aunque pueda ver las peticiones el "challenge" y la respuesta del cliente siempre van a ser diferente, el servidor puede validar la firma del cliente con la llave publica y si es satisfactorio entregar un token valido por un tiempo corto (minutos, horas, días, depende de tu aplicacion, o inclusive por un numero limitado de peticiones), ten en cuenta que entre mas seguido se tenga que generar el token mas afectara el rendimiento del sistema.

El token debe ser único así es comprometido puede excluirse como valido del servidor.
Lo mismo con la llaves privadas, debes implementar un mecanismo para invalidarlas si alguna se ve comprometida.

Esto hace bastante seguro conseguir el token, y complicado de encontrar la forma de obtenerlo (a pesar de esto con mucha paciencia y conocimiento, no es una tarea fácil, se pude llegar a hacer usando un sniffer y un depurador pegado al cliente)

Para evitar MiTM con certificados auto firmados puedes implementar un mecanismo de certificare pinning donde tu cliente solo acepta una lista propia de entidades certificadoras.